# Tmux horizontal split isn't working, instead it brings up a weird menu

Tags: terminal, tmux

So I use ctrl + a (bound to a instead of b), and I try to ctrl + a and release then type in SHIFT + ' which is "

so ctrl + a + " like the horizontal split should in theory work.

When I do that I get a weird menu (I'm not sure what this menu is, why it pops up, I'm trying to figure out how to correctly get the horizontal split to work)

[image: TMux "Horizontal Split" Menu given]

Comment: Side note: in tmux this is "vertical". See [this thread](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/213).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `choose-tree` menu (or perhaps one of the other `choose-...` commands).

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> to activate "Describe key binding" then press <kbd>"</kbd> to see what it reports.